# How to JTextField with JButtons?

Tags: jtextfield

I have created an app and my `JButton` will show, but I need to have a `JTextField` to enter in an amount and that will not show in my `JFrame`.  Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: You need a `JFrame` with a `JTextField` and a `JButton` on it?? Code says more then 1000 words :)

Comment: Prefer JFormattedTextField to JTextField